# Generic relations in superclass

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data Neo4j to write Java entities into a Neo4j database. The object model is rather generic:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode {
     @GraphId
     private Long id;

     @Index(primary = true, unique = true)
     private String uuid;

     @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
     private Set<AbstractNode> containsNode;

     ...
}

@NodeEntity
public class Country extends AbstractNode { ... }

@NodeEntity
public class Region extends AbstractNode { ... }

@NodeEntity
public class City extends AbstractNode { ... }
```

I am creating 1 Country. Into this Country I put 1 Region and in the Region I put 1 City. After that, I call `Neo4jRepository.save(country)` (on my own interface inheriting from Neo4jRepository, of course) to make the whole graph persistent:

`Country -> Region -> City`

In the logs of Neo4j Embedded, I can see that 1 Country, 1 Region and 1 City were persisted.

Now I load the Country in a fresh Session. The result is 1 Country with 1 Region. But the Region does not contain a City but the Country:

`Country -> Region -> Country`

How can I persist such generic object graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate a setter for `containsNode` with `@Relationship` as well:

```
// direction defaults to OUTGOING, using it here just for clarity
@Relationship(type = "CONTAINS", direction = "OUTGOING") 
public void setContainsNode(Set<AbstractNode> containsNode) {
    this.containsNode = containsNode;
}
```

When you don't do this OGM/SDN tries to match the incoming `CONTAINS` relationship on region from country and finds a setter of matching type and uses that. Using @Relationship on setter says this should be used for OUTGOING only and the objects than map correctly.